# select value in table containing a certain word, but exclude if it contains another

Tags: mysql

So i've got this query:

```
show tables in simhopp like '%competitor%'
```

Everytime i'm generating a new table, the keyword `competitor` is inserted before the actual name.

Also a 2nd table is also created but with the last word inserted being `judges`.

eg.

If i create table "list2017" my database would look like this:

```
competitorlist2017
competitorlist2017judges
```

How would i ONLY select the tables without the `judges` at the end?

Comment: like '%competitor%' and not like '%judges'

Comment: @Mihai if 'judges' is in the end then you don't need trailing `%` as well..

Comment: @DarshanMehta Just removed before your comment

Comment: @Mihai incorrect mysql syntax.

Comment: @DarshanMehta read again, selecting the judges IS NOT what i want, that's easy. But now i want to only select **competitorlist2017**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try from  WHERE  Tables_in_simhopp

```
  SHOW TABLES
  FROM  simhopp 
  WHERE 
      `Tables_in_simhopp` LIKE 'competitor%'
       AND  `Tables_in_simhopp`  NOT  LIKE '%judges';
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for more than one condition for SHOW TABLES is

```
SHOW TABLES FROM simhopp 
WHERE tables_in_simhopp LIKE '%competitor%'
AND tables_in_simhopp NOT LIKE '%judges'
```

Comment: mysql does not support this query.

Comment: @gordonlinoff I didn\`t even see the newest answer,but ofcourse this is hard to prove.I`m guessing a mistaken answer has to remain frozen forever to prevent that,but your edit already suggests you have made up your opinion.I was on rextester playing with it

Comment: @Mihai . . . I missed the effect that `in_simhopp` has on the results.  It tried to fix things . . . I rolled back my edits, upvoted you and scaisEdge and deleted my answer.